# Camel 3.x: Disable automatic registration of routes

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have been trying to migrate from Camel 2.x to 3.x and having some issues with Spring Boot integration.

With Camel 2.x, i managed to disable auto injection of `RouteBuilder` instances annotated with `@Component` but have the other benefits, camel-spring provides. I do that since i have a prototype bean that extends from RouteBuilder and i manually add them to camel context as required.

With Camel 3.x, i can't do that. I can't remove `@Component` annotation from the class since i need Spring to inject other dependencies to class. Is there a way do that with Camel 3.x?

Comment: It seems you need to disable auto-registration of routes. I have edited question title to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-discovery and registration of `RouteBuilder` instances to `CamelContext` can be disabled with property `camel.springboot.routes-collector-enabled=false`.

See [Camel Spring Boot docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.0.x/spring-boot.html):

> **camel.springboot.routes-collector-enabled**
>
> Whether the routes collector is enabled or not. When enabled Camel will auto-discover routes (RouteBuilder instances from the registry and also load additional XML routes from the file system. The routes collector is default enabled.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work. I have actually checked the camel properties but seems i missed this one.

Answer (score 0):

To disable Camel auto configuration (for example in tests)

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = CamelAutoConfiguration.class)
```